# How to validate multiple checkbox with input box using php?

Tags: php

I have following 12 checkbox and input box. I am getting checkbox and input box value using array called `ch_name[]` and `ch_for[]`

```
<div class="checkbox form-inline">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="ch_name[]" value="ch1">CH01</label>
    <input type="text" name="ch_for[]" value="" placeholder="Channel details" class="form-control ch_for">
</div>
```

Now I am calling Ajax request to validate if at least one checkbox is empty and also **corresponding** input box is empty.

So for that I am using following php code but somehow it's don't work. May be I am missing something :(

**Php Validation :**

```
$ch_name        = isset($_POST['ch_name']) ? $_POST['ch_name'] : '';
$ch_for         = isset($_POST['ch_for']) ? $_POST['ch_for'] : '';  

if( count($ch_name) > 0  ) {        
    if ( isset($ch_name, $ch_for) && !empty($ch_name) && !empty($ch_for) ) {
        foreach ( $ch_name as $key => $ch_name) {
            if( empty($_POST['ch_name']) ) {
                $errors[] = 'Select your channel name';
            }

            if( empty($ch_for[$key]) ) {
                $errors[] = "Enter your channel details";
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `somehow it's don't work` Then fix it __somehow__. Or explain what exactly does not work.

Comment: If any one checkbox and input box is empty then it will show error. And If I select number 7 checkbox but didn't enter corresponding input box value then it will show error message.